# When choosing $k$ elements from $n$, how to count number of subsets of size $m$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Consider a set of $n$ elements. If I choose $k$ elements, where $0\le k\le n$, this will be $\binom{n}{k}$. After making this choice, from the amount $\binom{n}{k}$ I want the number of possible subsets of size $m$, where $0\le m\le\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: There are too many letters in this question. Say you choose $2$ elements from a set of size $3$. There are $3$ ways of doing this. Now what is the purpose of $m$ here?

Comment: Say I have a set of 6 things and I want to choose 3 items. Out of those ways of choosing three items, I want to know how many have a continuous subset of size 2 (which is the m in this example)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I've reformatted your question to reflect better what I think you were after, hope this is ok. In your comment you have $\binom{6}{3}=20$ ways of choosing $3$ elements from $6$. Now what do you want to do next. You have $3$ things, so can form subsets of size $1$, $2$, or $3$. Also what do you mean by continuous subset, I think you just mean subset.

Comment: Yes, I mean just subset, and the reformat looks like exactly what I'm after. Thanks!

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, I'm concerned with the position these items were in when they were selected. so say you have a list: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. You select three things, how many ways of the ways can you select three things and have a selection were there are m adjacent items in the selection, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:** See if the following can be of any help in answering your question.

As an example if we view the $6$ letters
$$A\,B\,C\,D\,E\,F$$
as a list that we wish to subdivide into three sets, then there are $6-1=5$ gaps for us to place our dividing line, say as in
$$A\,|B\,C\,|D\,E\,F$$
so by dividing into three sets we have had to use $3-1=2$ lines. Hence we can do this in $\tbinom {6-1}{3-1}=\tbinom {5}{2}=10$ ways in total.

In general if we view the $n$ elements as a list, such as for $A\,B\,C\,D\,E\,F$  having $n - 1$ gaps, one between each pair of consecutive letters, then we may, or may not, place a line there such as in $A\,|B$. One has to choose $k - 1$ of them to actually contain a line; therefore there are $\tbinom {n-1}{k-1}$ possible ways of placing these lines.

---

Consider now our $n$ elements. Let us subdivide them into $j$ subsets, $k_i$, where $1\le i\le j$, and $k_1+k_2+\dotsb+k_j=n$. We can choose $k_1$ elements from them in $\binom{n}{k_1}$ ways. From the remaining  $n - k_1$ elements we can choose $k_2$ elements in  $\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}$, and so on until we reach $k_j$. In total we have 
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k_1}\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}\binom{n-k_1-k_2}{k_3}\dots&=\frac{n!}{(n-k_1)!k_1!}\frac{(n-k_1)!}{(n-k_1-k_2)!k_2!}\frac{(n-k_1-k_2)!}{(n-k_1-k_2-k_3)!k_3!}\dots\\
&=\frac{n!}{k_1!\,k_2!\dotsm\,k_j!}\\
&=\binom{n!}{k_1!,\,k_2!,\dotsc,\,k_j!}
\end{align*}
whereby cancellation gives the last term, called a multinomial coefficient.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's an interesting question. In your comment it made more *sense* in a way than the question. i.e. given $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$, you select three things, say $1,3,5$ and you want how many ways you get $m$ adjacent numbers, like $1,3,5$ has three adjacent things, and $1,5,3$ has two, as only $1$ and $5$ are adjacent in the sense of increasing order (if that's what you meant). I think you should reformulate your question with this example, maybe, and list everything you've thought of, as then people will be better able to help you as they can see what it is you're after.